# SSMS shows 'Querying transaction count' on closing the query window

Tags: ssms

My job usually involves starting SSMS in the morning.
There are multiple query tabs open at any given time during the day.
At the end of the day when I go to close them I get this window

[image: Query Transactin Count]

This did not happen with earlier version of SSMS.
Is there a setting which enables/disables this?

Running SSMS v18.11.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the link for details about this behavior: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/773315/ssms-hangs-for-an-extended-period-when-closing-a-q.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/773315/ssms-hangs-for-an-extended-period-when-closing-a-q.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Last line there says it all: "But if you have five windows open and you are closing SSMS, and you get one dialog per window, it's still kind of irritating." This first showed up for me in 18.12.1. MS needs to provide an option to disable this.

Comment: @JohnChase we assigned Ctrl-Shift-F4 to disconnect and Ctrl-F4 to close tab. Still annoying but less annoying.

Comment: @Lambda showed the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75266933/2997016 (at least for V19)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not a solution, but if I disconnect the query before closing the tab I don't get the popup. I added a disconnect button to the toolbar to make it less intrusive.

And I've since assigned the keys so Ctrl-Shift-F4 to disconnect and Ctrl-F4 to close so that makes multiple tabs less annoying.

Answer (score 77):

Fixed At last in V19

[image]

Will not work with existing open query, but will with new ones

Comment: This is the answer.
Never had this window in V18, updated tot V19 and it started showing up. Disabled the check and now no more popups during closing of SSMS

Comment: Thank you!  This was annoying - like a SQL DBA doesn't know how many transactions are opened.

Comment: any workaround for v18?

Comment: @Gabe - yes just install v19 or use one of the workarounds already posted on this page.

Comment: Here is the link for [v19](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) incase anyone needs it.

Comment: Finally, it was so annoying.

Answer (score 24):

#### SSMS 18 (workaround):

Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced > *Disconnect after the query executes*: ☑

#### SSMS 19:

Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > General > *Check for open connections before closing T-SQL query windows*: ◻

Answer (score 22):

I usually right click on in the query window, go to "Connection" and then click "Disconnect All Queries" to disconnect all and then you can close SSMS.

See Here

[image: 1]

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. In my case, I knew I had lost my connection and I restarted for a clean connection, but every `SQL` window does this upon closing it. Since I had lost connection, I had to wait for it to time out for every window that I had open. I have found that manually clearing the windows makes it quicker, but I'd like to disable this `query transaction count`, so it does not try to run when closing every window. This started after the last updated version of the tool.

Comment: This is a really frustrating feature isn't it.  I have a VPN on a work laptop which means if it is disconnected when I want to close SMSS it causes a convoluted workflow to just close the program!

Comment: Definitely a new "feature" from the last update. Never had this before. And it is annoying ah! Every single time i close a query window ... Modal popup "Querying transaction count......" .... and if I close SSMS with 7 windows open.... SEVEN MODALS in a freaking row!!!  ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️  WTH MS???

Comment: This is still happening with the version v18.12.1.


I can also confirm that it happens when I have reset the VPN connection by some reason.
In my case I use two different VPNs and if I'm querying a DB in VPN#1 and then switch to VPN#2, I need to close or disconnect the query first, otherwise it will hang in there. If I try to close SSMS after a VPN change then I get the window for the transaction count warning.


So, the way I see it is this being a disclaimer or a debug window to show what is happening instead of the SSMS hanging the UI.

Comment: Really frustrating indeed, and lossing precious time. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that will happen upon losing connection and then attempting to close out query tabs. Try verifying your login credentials and ensuring you are connected before closing them out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So, there is no solution or settings to disable this?

Comment: I get this error when my multi-factor-authentication token expires and I need to re-login with updated credentials.  So losing connection is certainly a factor.  "Verifying your login credentials" isn't helpful because I can't change them until I close and reopen the SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is currently not a setting/option to ignore that popup, however, the SQL/365 community page is saying they are looking at this though. That was 2 months ago so more votes to add a disable option for this should push it further up the priority list.

Both the original request and duplicate'ish request are below.
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aaaad978-65b9-ec11-a81c-6045bd80aaa9

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f7b022a3-0002-ed11-a81b-6045bd853c94

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/9da59e82-f8fd-ec11-a81b-6045bd8606d4

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, this was caused by a GDI handle leak in the Cisco system tray status icon (csc_ui.exe).

I have to give credit to a post by Scott MacPhee on this Azure forum: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aaaad978-65b9-ec11-a81c-6045bd80aaa9

After reading that post, I right-clicked on the "Cisco Secure Client" icon in my system tray and selected "Quit". This closed the status icon without affecting my VPN connection in any way (I connect to this computer through a VPN using Cisco AnyConnect).

All of my problems with SSMS immediately went away: The "Querying Transaction Count" message no longer appears, intellisense is no longer laggy, everything feels faster.

As Scott mentioned, you can see the leak by adding "GDI objects" to the list of columns shown in the Details pane of the Task Manager. csc_ui.exe had more than 6,000 GDI handles before I closed it. Out of curiosity, I restarted it, and now it has 174.

Here is Scott's post in it's entirety, as it provides some additional helpful details:

> Possible Fix: disable csc_ui.exe (Cisco system tray icon)
>
> Version: SSMS v18.12.1
>
> Symptom:
> After a few days of system uptime, SSMS pops up a 'Querying transaction count' >window when closing tabs.
> Restarting SSMS does not help. Restarting the computer does, for a bit.
>
> Other system lagginess after a few days (one test, dragging/resizing an empty >notepad window is very choppy, 1-4 fps), regardless of SSMS running.
>
> Looking at task manager (details pane, GDI objects column added)
> I traced my root issue to a GDI object leak in an 'csc_ui.exe', which had >4000+ objects held after a few days uptime.
>
> This is an application unrelated to SSMS, but a component of our Cisco VPN >endpoint security suite, and it was recently updated when I noticed the issues >start.
>
> Killing the csc_ui.exe process immediately restored system performance, and >eliminated the 'Querying transaction count' popup in useless cases. (it still >pops if the server connection was lost, which is appropriate for me).
>
> This buggy application seems to be a system tray icon for displaying status >for Cisco endpoint security software to the user, but not necessary for system >protection. Our IT/Security team was able to remove csc_ui.exe deployment from >our systems without impacting security.
>
> We fixed this in November, and none of my teammates have had the issue in the >2 months since.
>
> It is likely that a lot of VPN using comments in this thread are running the >same Cisco software, and should work with their IT teams to try disabling >csc_ui.exe.
>
> Wild hypothesis:
> This doesn't really seem to be an SSMS bug at all, but the legacy windows (1.0?) GDI mechanism that allows a buggy application to slow down the system, causing a SSMS timeout to inappropriately fire, causing the annoying popup.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I just noticed, this "Querying transaction count" dialog does not popup if I open Visual Studio when closing a tab in SSMS that was open being opening VS2022. Further testing reveals the dialog does not show as often when Visual Studio is open. I have opened and closed 100's of tabs and it is less frequent with Visual Studio 2022 open, especially if a solution and projects are loaded.

I just started experiencing this annoying feature today. I updated to the latest version a week ago not sure why it just started happening, I was in SSMS for 12 hours yesterday never happened. Maybe something I changed in Visual Studio 2022 changed a config file or registry entry that SSMS uses.

I did notice, the following avoids the dialog.

Right click on a tab:

1. Close all tabs
2. Close all tabs but this one, then close the last one
3. Execute a long running query, close the tab while the query is executing, click yes to cancel the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can upvote a change on Azure.com:
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aaaad978-65b9-ec11-a81c-6045bd80aaa9

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling third-party SQL software permanently removed the "Querying transaction count" popup for me and fixed this issue.  I added the details on another Stack Overflow post.

[Remove the popup message after removing the SQL document in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73213582/remove-the-popup-message-after-removing-the-sql-document-in-sql-server/74692834#74692834)

Answer (score -1):

Unchecking [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W74uf.png) resolved the issue.

Comment: does not seem to work

Comment: It worked on 2 machines that I tested.

Comment: This does not work. Also no explanation why it should work. Why would not showing miscellaneous files stop SSMS from doing the transaction count query or make the query go faster?