# Remove the popup message after removing the SQL document in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Goal**: don't display the popup when you remove/delete the SQL document in SQL Server.

**Problem**: before I downloaded the latest version of SQL Server, it didn't show any popup about status when I removed the SQL document.

When I downloaded the latest version of SQL Server, it suddenly started to display the popup.

It always displays when I remove/delete the SQL document in SQL Server.

How do I remove it?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no "good" solution to this at the moment, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71806872/7165279) and [this feedback item I opened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/773315/ssms-hangs-for-an-extended-period-when-closing-a-q.html) for a lot more detail on what's going on. Note that I opened my feedback item about a prior version of SSMS (before the popup was even shown), but read through the comments for discussion about the dialog.

Comment: I keep up to date with SSMS versions, currently on 18.11.1 and about to update it; I've never seen this dialog, ever.

Comment: @Stu I typically only see it if I am connecting via a VPN. When the VPN goes down this *modal* dialog box stays open for the full connection timeout duration as SSMS wants to check `@@trancount` before letting the window close. In these cases the dialog box status is of course "failed", not "success". Extremely annoying if you have multiple windows open and lose the VPN. Task manager is the antidote there. I don't know the conditions under which you see it and it succeeds... maybe high latency connections, or connections that are broken but which can be re-established.

Comment: In my environment I use SSMS on a desktop windows10 machine, it connects to several local on-premises SQL servers and numerous cloud-based SQL Servers over a VPN, including several DEV and UAT boxes and a production AG cluster running on VMs at 2 different provider sites. The VPN between local and remote provider has dropped on numerous occaisons, sometimes for extended periods of hours, or connectivity is interrupted somewhere in the cloud network as recently as this weekend due to a firewall update; there are 15 team members using SSMS, none of use have seen this ever (doesn't help I know :)

Comment: @Stu if the VPN has already reconnected by the time you try to close the window then the trancount check will return immediately so you don't get the popup. I said I raised a feedback item, I actually opened the Q&A item. The feedback item is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aaaad978-65b9-ec11-a81c-6045bd80aaa9) with 174 votes. Other than being a nuisance, this actually costs people money: if they had a window open against an azure sql database set to auto pause, then go to close an old window, SSMS issues `select @@trancount` which restarts the database.

Comment: It was 173 votes a few minutes ago ;-) I've definitely closed query tabs / SSMS completely while being disconnected, still not (for some reason) affected by this.

Comment: If the query window itself is disconnected no check is performed. So one option is to manually disconnect the query window first (which *doesn't* do the check, for... reasons) before closing it. I use an autohotkey macro on a side mouse button (ctrl +q, d then ctrl + f4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Uninstalling third-party SQL software permanently removed the "Querying transaction count" popup for me. Details are below.***

---

I downloaded Devart's "SQL Tools" pack.  It was one installation file
that installed the 15 separate applications into SQL Server Management Studio.  I didn't even open any of the applications yet or activate the free trial (not sure if it activates automatically or not), and ever since have been receiving the "Querying transaction count" popup every time a query window is closed.

This was reducing my productivity, so I spent a few hours researching how to remove this popup so I don't have to click the close button thousands of times.  SSMS didn't update, there weren't any options within SSMS or Devart to remove this popup, and there weren't any solutions online other than to create a macro to replicate multiple keyboard strokes to disconnect the connection first and then close the query window.

I ended up uninstalling these 15 applications, and without even needing to restart my PC, the "Querying transaction count" stopped appearing.  As an added bonus, the annoying "Buy Devart" PC ads with the too-tiny-to-click-to-close-X that were also popping up every few hours (15+ popup ads a day during Black Friday sale too) stopped appearing as well!  Hallelujah!  Maybe someone else experiencing this "Querying transaction count" `SELECT @@trancount` popup installed third-party software like Devart's and just needs to uninstall it.

The software below looks amazing and I'm still interested in trying them out if the free trial didn't automatically activate and expire, but will probably install them one at a time so I can figure out which of the 15 programs is causing this popup.  SQL Complete was the only one that I kept and is not causing the popup, so it's 1 of the other 14.

### Devart's SQL Tools

1. SQL Complete ***(Not Causing Popup)***
2. Source Control
3. Unit Test
4. Schema Compare
5. Data Compare
6. Data Generator
7. Documenter
8. Data Pump
9. Index Manager
10. Query Builder
11. Search
12. Monitor
13. Event Profiler
14. SQL Decryptor
15. DevOps Automation